# Automator workflow to search selection - "There was a problem with the input to the service"

Tags: automator

I have bult a simple Automator workflow called "Search with duckduckgo" which is supposed to search the selected text in any application using duckduckgo in my default browser. My workflow works properly in some applications, and it fails, most notatbly in Preview when I am trying to search words from a PDF. I get the error message "There was a problem with the input to the service".

Can you explain the error message, the proper way to debug it, and how to get to to work?

My workflow: I selected `Workflow recieves/text` and then I have a `Run javascript` with the function below to build the URL, I finally, I used `Display Webpages`

```
function run(input, parameters) {
   return "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" + encodeURI(input)
}
```

I am using MacOS Catalina, and here are screenshots.

[My Automator worflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9FZZ.png)

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWdWf.png)

Comment: I don't know javascript, but the `input` argument is an _array_, so you would need to coerce or get a specific item from it (such as the first one).

Comment: I inserted a "copy to clipboard" bit before the javascrpt and it still fails with the same error when I run it from Preview, and I can paste whatever I used from other applications. So I don't think the problem is in the javascript, it seems to me that for some reason, Preview does not properly send the selection data to the workflow? This is my first with Automator, so I don't know if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Is it possible that some of the characters you're trying to send can't be encoded for javascript? It would really help if you could give a specific test-case (some file we could download from the net, with a specific line that consistently fails). It's hard to fix a problem without being able to see it in action.

Comment: it *never* works in Preview. For the sake of argument, searching any word from [this research report](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/mrp_voterfile_20181030.pdf) just shows the error message below. I suspect Preview does not send the selected text to the workflow. Using this same pdf in the Chrome PDF viewer works.